# Lost layout after onConfigurationChanged()

Tags: android

I've been searching quite a while now but still no luck. Changing the code to the now edited version.
**EDITED**
On application start with this in onCreate:

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.game_activity);
    . . . . .
```

The app still works flawless.
In onConfigurationChange() I removed the setContentView() so the switch actualy does nothing at all:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) 
{
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
switch(newConfig.orientation)
{
case Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT:
    break;
case Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE:
        break;
}
}   //  onConfigurationChanged()
```

Now the blanc screens are gone, that's a relieve.
But;
When tha app is started in P-mode and configuration changed to L-mode the layout remains the same as in P-mode and visa versa.

I suddenly have a hunch!
The activity is only started once! That's exactly what I want, but it means also that the code there is only executed once.  I have to check that first.

**EDIT**

OK, checked out all that was necessary.  But the problem remains.

When starting up the app in portrait mode every things is fine.  But when I change to landscape mode the configuration change is caried out only the portrait layout is still used and vice versa.

I do have different layouts for different orientations in the xml.
I also have

```
 android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" >
```

in the manifest.

I'm out of options, any help will be most appreciated.

**EDIT AGAIN**

It was hard to proof but I succeded.
This is in the XML one for portrait mode one for landscape mode:

```
<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/portGame480x800"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:tag="layout_game_activity"
tools:context=".MeMoInfoActivity" >
.....
</LinearLayout



<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/landGame480x800"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:baselineAligned="false"
android:tag="layout-land_game_activity"
tools:context=".MeMoInfoActivity" >
....
</LinearLayout>
```

This the code:

```
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) 
{
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

Log.i(TAG, "***************************\nMeMoGameActivity onConfigurationChanged\n***************************"); 

switch(newConfig.orientation)
{
case Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT:
        Toast.makeText(this, "portrait", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        LinearLayout portLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.portGame480x800);
        if(portLayout != null)
        {
            String portTag = (String) portLayout.getTag().toString();
            Log.i(TAG, "Portrait portTag: "+portTag);
        }
break;
case Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE:
        Toast.makeText(this, "Landscape", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        LinearLayout landLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.landGame480x800);
        if(landLayout != null)
        {
            String landTag = (String) landLayout.getTag().toString();

            Log.i(TAG, "LansScape landTag: "+landTag);
        }
        break;
}
}   //  onConfigurationChanged()
```

And this is the out from logcat:

```
09-30 17:10:32.376: I/MeMoGame(2509): ***************************
09-30 17:10:32.376: I/MeMoGame(2509): MeMoGameActivity onConfigurationChanged
09-30 17:10:32.376: I/MeMoGame(2509): ***************************

09-30 17:10:32.534: I/MeMoGame(2509): LANDSCAPE InfoActivity dispWidthPX: 800


09-30 17:11:02.234: I/MeMoGame(2509): ***************************
09-30 17:11:02.234: I/MeMoGame(2509): MeMoGameActivity onConfigurationChanged
09-30 17:11:02.234: I/MeMoGame(2509): ***************************

09-30 17:11:02.384: I/MeMoGame(2509): Portrait portTag: layout_game_activity

09-30 17:11:02.384: I/MeMoGame(2509): PORTRAIT InfoActivity dispWidthPX: 480

09-30 17:11:02.896: D/dalvikvm(2509): GC_CONCURRENT freed 102K, 3% free 6320K/6471K, paused 19ms+7ms, total 320ms
```

The app was started in portrait mode.  It is quit clear that it never executed the landscape layout.

Can / will someone help please?

Comment: Is there a compelling reason not to let Android handle this with different resource folders (e.g. layout-land and layout-port folders)?

Comment: @Tanis; I tried that too, it wont work.

Comment: If "it won't work" means that you get the same white screen, then I am inclined to blame your layouts themselves.

Comment: Pretty sure that you need to remove `orientation` from your `configChanges` attribute to make Android use different layouts for protrait / landscape.

Answer (score 3):

You should let Android framework decide what layout shall be used based on the current configuration. So create 2 folders, `layout-land` and `layout-port`, and put your layouts (it's important to use the same filename). Also, remove that switches in the code.

Comment: Tried that also, no luck. I found the idea with the switches on this site. It fills me with great hope, but....

Comment: You mention a Toast in your quesiton... could you please post your complete code or at least a bit more of what we have now? Thanks.